# asp.net core check route attribute in middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to build some ASP.Net core middleware.

It needs see if the current route is marked as [Authorize].

eg:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if(context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
    {
        // check if route is marked as [Authorize]
        // and then do some logic
    }

    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved or if it's even possible?

If not, what would be a good alternative approach?

Comment: It would be too early in the pipeline to know which route was choosen

Comment: Was wondering about that. Couldn't find any definite answer on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just self-answering to close the question.

Doesn't seem like it's possible to do this as it's too early in the pipeline.

Comment: Out of date (I think), 3 years later, we now have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809568/3505377 | Just remember to [`services.AddControllers()` and `app.UseEndpoints(e => {e.MapControllerRoute( ... );})`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: HansElsen's solution is the answer

Answer (score 38):

I believe it can be achieved in a middleware class via:

```
var hasAuthorizeAttribute = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>().Endpoint.Metadata
                .Any(m => m is AuthorizeAttribute);
```

Answer (score 18):

HansElsen's answer is correct, but I would like to add some things to note about it:

1. You can use the extension method `context.GetEndpoint()` which is exactly the same as `context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>().Endpoint`
2. The endpoint will always be `null` if you set up your middleware before calling `app.UseRouting()` in your `Startup.cs`:

Don't do:

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
app.UseRouting();
```

Do:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

Comment: This is absolutely the answer I need. You were right on the money!

Comment: Thanks for the info about middleware setup order

Comment: Changing the order was what I needed as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Without knowing exactly what you want to achieve, it's a bit tricky to answer, but I suggest you have a look at the controller filters : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters

I put together an example:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Insert(0, new CustomFilter()));
}
```

**CustomFilter.cs**

```cs
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
        {
            var controllerInfo = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            var hasAuthorizeAttr = controllerInfo.ControllerTypeInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(_ => _.AttributeType == typeof(AuthorizeAttribute));
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // NOP
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was trying to read route data in middleware. Looks like it might not be possible

Comment: Downvoted as it's out of date and @HansElsen's answer achives what the OP was after in modern ASPNET Core.